# PROC SQL: How do i put multiple queries in one so the solutions are side by side?

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I have three queries. 1) count * records in one table 2) counts records that are matched or just not used for reason 1 3) counts records that are matched and just not used for reason 2

How Do I put the 3 queries into one and add query 2 and 3 together at once so I do not have to have two- three columns. So in excel in looks like:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeXk0.jpg

```
 /* 1 */ /* This finds amount of records */
    proc sql; 
    create table
      work.Original_count
    as 
    select
        count(*) as occurences
    from 
        WORK.query_for_reports1 as t1;
    quit;

    /* 2 *//* counts how many records are already matched  in technique ED*/ /* 10 */ 
    proc sql; 
    create table
         work.occ_matched_T1
    as 
    select
        count(*) as occurences 
    from 
       work.QUERY_FOR_REPORTS1 as t1 
    where t1.EdSYS is not null;
    quit;

    /*3 */ /* Counts how many records are already matched with IP */ /* 9 */
    proc sql; 
    create table 
        work.occ_matched_t1_1
    as 
    select 
           count(*) as occurences 
    from 
        work.E_DATA_UNMATCHED as t1
    where t1.Ip is not null;

quit;
```

Comment: "so I do not have to have two- three columns" yet the example shows columns.  Did you mean so you don't have 2-3 rows and shows them in columns? Rows go down columns go across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
proc sql;
create table wanted as
select t1.occurences as original_count
      ,t2.occurences as matched_by_T1
      ,t3.occurences as matched_by_T2
      ,t2.occurences+t3.occurences as B2_C2
from (select count(*) as occurences from query_for_reports1) t1
    ,(select count(*) as occurences from query_for_reports1 where edsys is not null) t2
    ,(select count(*) as occurences from e_data_unmatched where ip is not null) t3
;
quit;
```